# how to redim preserve jagged array (arrays in array) in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, jagged-arrays

I have an array of arrays (not a 2D array) in EXCEL VBA and I need to add elements to the inner arrays.
e.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayofArrays()

Dim OuterArray() As Variant
ReDim OuterArray(0 To 0)

Dim InnerArray() As Variant
ReDim InnerArray(0 To 0)

InnerArray(0) = "Foo"
OuterArray(0) = InnerArray

ReDim Preserve OuterArray(LBound(OuterArray) To UBound(OuterArray) + 1)
End Sub
```

I could now access the inner element by:

```
debug.print OuterArray(0)(0)
```

which prints me "Foo"

But how can I extend the array inside OuterArray?

The last line only adds an empty element to the OuterArray:

```
ReDim Preserve OuterArray(LBound(OuterArray) To UBound(OuterArray) + 1)
```

But what I want is this:

¦___OuterArray(0)

¦_____________OuterArray(0)(0): "Foo"

¦_____________OuterArray(0)(1): "Bar"

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you re-dimming `InnerArray`?

Comment: You need to redim the inner array, give him the value and after that insert the inner in the outer. Make sense?

Comment: Your answer is the same like Tom's answer. Thanks I made it work with the temp array copying back to then to the outerArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VBA` won't allow you to directly `ReDim` the inner array however, you can achieve it quite easily by using an intermediary helper array (in this example named `tmp`)

```
Option Explicit
Sub ArrayofArrays()
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim OuterArray() As Variant
    ReDim OuterArray(0 To 0)

    Dim InnerArray() As Variant
    ReDim InnerArray(0 To 0)

    InnerArray(0) = "Foo"
    OuterArray(0) = InnerArray

    tmp = OuterArray(0)
    ReDim Preserve tmp(LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp) + 1)
    OuterArray(0) = tmp
    Erase tmp

    OuterArray(0)(1) = "Bar"
    Debug.Print OuterArray(0)(1)
End Sub
```